# Raw literal strings in Julia

Tags: string, escaping, string-literals, julia

In Python one can write `r"a\nb"` in order to prevent the `\n` from being interpreted as an escape sequence for newline.

Is there something similar in Julia? And what about string interpolation like `"$variable"`, is there a way to prevent it?

I know one can simply write `"a\\nb"` and `"\$variable"` in Julia, but I would like to write a lot of LaTeX strings without having to care to proper escape every backslash `\` and dollar `$` characters...

(In Julia, `r"..."` creates a regular expression.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Julia 0.6](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md#library-improvements-1) we have `raw"\a$variable"`

Answer (score 14):

Ok, I just found out that since one can easily create [non-standard string literals](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#non-standard-string-literals) in Julia, a pass-through one will do what I was asking for:

```
macro R_str(s)
    s
end

>>> R"$a\n$b"
"\$a\\n\$b"
>>> print(R"$a\n$b")
$a\n$b
```

I also discovered that [PyPlot.jl](https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl) defines a «[LaTeXString](https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl#latex-plot-labels) type which can be constructed via `L"...."` without escaping backslashes or dollar signs», with the additional benefit of rendered equations in IJulia.

A last question remains: is not worth it to have a raw string literal in Julia base?

Comment: I have also found the need for the ``R_str`` macro on some occasions, and it is a hassle to define it manually. Not sure why it is not there, but open a PR or an issue on github, so that we can see if there are opposition against it.

Comment: @ivarne, I would like to make a PR indeed. I'll try to find some time to work on it (I want to use string flags to instruct the raw string macro to conditionally enable interpretation of character escape or interpolation).

Comment: It’s not really the “raw literal”. Try this: `R"C:\"`. It is trying to escape `"`. You have to add space: `R"C:\ "`. Your solution is very close. ps. Raw strings (or function that escape characters) for windows user might be interesting.

Comment: The `L` tip is exactly what I needed for Latex and PyPlot, thanks.

Comment: @DarekNędza: This is how it works in Python as well. `r"C:\"` is not a valid Python raw string. If it were, there'd be no way to write double quotes inside a raw, double-quoted string.