# How to define a macro everywhere in Julia?

Tags: parallel-processing, macros, julia

I have a trivial macro

```
macro lit_str(s)
    s
end
```

which I am using to generate regex patterns.  (Context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882353/raw-literal-strings-in-julia)). Normally I have this wrapped in a module called HelperFunctions (and export it using ```export @lit_str).  I'm trying to use it in a function called via RemoteRef, but even if I do

@everywhere using HelperFunctions

I get an error like

```
exception on exception on 3: exception on 2: 4: ERROR: @lit_str not defined
 in eval at C:\cygwin\home\vagrant\buildbot\slave\package_win8_1-x64\build\base\sysimg.jl:7
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1305
 in anonymous at multi.jl:855
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:621
 in anonymous at task.jl:855
ERROR: @lit_str not defined
 in eval at C:\cygwin\home\vagrant\buildbot\slave\package_win8_1-x64\build\base\sysimg.jl:7
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1305
 in anonymous at multi.jl:855
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:621
 in anonymous at task.jl:855
ERROR: @lit_str not defined
 in eval at C:\cygwin\home\vagrant\buildbot\slave\package_win8_1-x64\build\base\sysimg.jl:7
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1305
 in anonymous at multi.jl:855
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:621
 in anonymous at task.jl:855
```

Is there any way to export a macro so it can be used by processes spawned with remoteref?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a no-brainer, but I'll put the solution here in case anyone else has the same issue.  I needed to do

```
addprocs(numprocs)
```

before

```
@everywhere using WhatNot
```

since I was doing this in Jupyter and not by calling `julia -p 8 myfile.jl`.